# Error "Usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado"

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema con UcanAccess, el cual es al usar la clausula WHERE, me tira un error.

ConnectAccess.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectAccess {

static String rutaDB;
static String user;
static String pass;
static String sql;

public static String getRutaDB() {
    return rutaDB;
}
public void setRutaDB(String rutaDB) {
    ConnectAccess.rutaDB = rutaDB;
}

public static String getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    ConnectAccess.user = user;
}

public static String getPass() {
    return pass;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    ConnectAccess.pass = pass;
}

public static String getSql() {
    return sql;
}
public void setSql(String sql) {
    ConnectAccess.sql = sql;
}




public void conectar(){
    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+rutaDB,user,pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("Usuario"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("Contraseña"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("Permiso"));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    ConnectAccess ca = new ConnectAccess();

    ca.setRutaDB("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/usuarios.accdb");
    ca.setUser(null);
    ca.setPass(null);
    ca.setSql("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario=admin");
    ca.conectar();
}

}
```

Si quito "WHERE Usuario=admin" si me funciona, pero al quitarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: ADMIN
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)
    at ConnectAccess.conectar(ConnectAccess.java:50)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: ADMIN
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:208)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: ADMIN
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la columna `usuario` es una cadena de caracteres (`char`, `varchar` o similares), deguramente `admin` es una cadena de caracteres también, por lo que la manera correcta de escribir el código sería:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    ConnectAccess ca = new ConnectAccess();

    ca.setRutaDB("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/usuarios.accdb");
    ca.setUser(null);
    ca.setPass(null);
    ca.setSql("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario='admin' ");
    ca.conectar();
}

}
```

Recuerda que debes encerrar entre comillas todas las cadenas de caracteres. Esto es válido casi para cualquier lenguaje, incluido el SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

   ConnectAccess ca = new ConnectAccess();

   ca.setRutaDB("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/usuarios.accdb");
   ca.setUser(null);
   ca.setPass(null);
   ca.setSql("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario=admin");
   ca.conectar();
   }

}
```

Creo que el error está en ese código puede ser como no.

Te lo digo xq generalmente cuando mostramos un código que contiene usuarios y contraseñas no lo ocultamos con "null" sino con "usuario" y "contrasena" respectiva ya sea en español o en inglés.

Aventuro por ese lado, por lo que puede serque en setUser y en setPass no estés enviando de forma correcta los datos de autenticación a la base de datos.

Puede ser que el getString no estés funcionando del todo bien, prueba enviar los datos directamente en el código

Answer (score 0):

fijate en el archivo:

> C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/usuarios.accdb

si tenes una tabla con el nombre ADMIN.
en caso de que lo tengas fijate el schema puesto.

Comment: saludos y gracias por el apoyo, toma en consideración que estas respondiendo una pregunta de hace 2 años y segundo no eres claro en tu publicación, no se entiende por que debe hacer lo que pides